# NSRangeException index 9 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using `NSRange` to divide an array of 100 into 10 and storing them in array of array. I'm getting the following error when I scroll down to the last section in `UITableView` and I'm using indexed `UITableView`.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615
>   beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'

The following is my code :

```
    var tableData : NSMutableArray!
    var mutA  = NSMutableArray()
    var indexOfNumbers = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        tableData = [
            // 100 lines of string array of different starting letter
        ]

        let indexNumbers = "0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
        indexOfNumbers = indexNumbers.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            var halfArray : NSArray!
            var theRange = NSRange()

            theRange.location = i*10;
            theRange.length = tableData.count / 10
                halfArray = tableData.subarrayWithRange(theRange)
            mutA.addObject(halfArray)
        }
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return indexOfNumbers.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = mutA[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return indexOfNumbers
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
        let temp = indexOfNumbers as NSArray
        return temp.indexOfObject(title)
    }
```

I have no idea of what's going on.

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: FYI - the question title and the error are quite different.

Comment: Not any specific line, it shows the e`App delegate` !

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint in the debugger so it stop on the line causing the problem.

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to see on which line the code crashes.

Comment: alright, i will get back to you in a bit , it crashes in the following line : `cell.textLabel?.text = mutA[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as? String` @rmaddy

Comment: Why aren't your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods based on the your `mutA` variable? Do that and your issue will be fixed.

Comment: 18446744073709551615 is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF = UInt.max = NSNotFound. A possible cause it that in `temp.indexOfObject(title)` the given title was not found in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is based on the `mutA` variable but your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` methods are not.

Change `numberOfSectionsInTableView` to:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return mutA.count
}
```

Change `numberOfRowsInSection` to:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mutA[section].count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let indexNumbers = "0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100"
    indexOfNumbers = indexNumbers.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
```

Here you put 11 strings in indexOfNumbers

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        ...
        mutA.addObject(halfArray)
    }
```

Here you put 9 items in mutA.

Then you tell UITableView there are 11 sections, guess what will be thrown when you try mutA[10]?

Comment: The loop adds 9 items, not 8.